# Unable to display single custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am showing the projects added customly on to my home page by simple queering them. using these lines of code

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'recent-projects', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ,'order' => 'ASC');
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo get_post_permalink( $post->ID, $leavename, $sample );
    endwhile;
```

when i click on the permalink of the custom posts then it is showing me the index page. while i have archive.php too.
here is the code from functions.php.

```
register_post_type( 'recent-projects',
// CPT Options
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Recent Projects' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Recent Project' )
        ),
        'taxonomies' => array('recordings', 'category', 'whatever'),  //add this....
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'recent-projects'),
        'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'trackbacks',
        'custom-fields',
        'comments',
        'revisions',
        'thumbnail',
        'author',
        'page-attributes',)

    )
);
```

and this is the code in file named archive-recent-projects.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="content-area">
    <div class="container main_content_wrap">
      <div class="page_wrapper">  

        <section id="site-main" class="site-main content-part" >        
            <div class="blog-post">
                <h1 class="classic-title"><span>Recent Projects</span></h1>
                <br>
                <br>
                <ul>
                <?php
                    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'recent-projects','order' => 'ASC');
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
                       <li>
                        <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></small><br>
                        <strong>-</strong>  <?php the_title(); ?><br> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read</a><br><br>
                    </li>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
            </ul>
            </div>        
        </section>
        </div><!--end .page_wrapper-->
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Just on a side note. You don't need to add `, $leavename, $sample` inside the `get_post_permalink`

Comment: Is this `<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>` that is outputting your custom post type loop? If so, then try moving it outside the `while loop` in your `archive-recent-projects.php` template.

Comment: @WizardCoder i updated my  archive-recent-projects.php, have a look at it again please.

Comment: Since creating the custom post type have you gone in to your permalinks settings page in the admin area and clicked save?

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID` for `get_post_permalink`. `$post->ID` will get the ID of the current page, which in your case is the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

```
$recent_posts = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'recent-projects',
'posts_per_page' => 10 ,
'order' => 'ASC'
));
if($recent_posts->have_posts()) :
    while($recent_posts->have_posts()) : $recent_posts->the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
        the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I have posted this code in archive-recent-projects.php but its still not working.